Manga when the black hair fl reincarnated into the hospital where she was donating blood and pinned the nurse down
She has black hair, she was reincarnated and was well know in that world, she knows medicine and martial arts

apart from reincarnation, is there any magic or sci/fi? When did you read it? was it black and white or color?

Its a Manhua so colored, and its written in modern time but apart from that I can’t remember much about it, I read some on mltmanga before they shut down so its new
